How do I avoid sending these two variables from method to method forever?
Java newbie here. I am creating a small text adventure game to practice. On the main method I initialize the dineros (money) and rep (reputation) variables and call the method with the start of the game, which also calls a method to print current dineros and rep. I intend to call printStats pretty much almost everytime a new block of text is shown aka every little step in the game. But what I noticed is that: main initializes dineros and rep, and calls startTrain with them - because startTrain needs them to then send them to printStats which it calls. If I do something like "if press A, call method getOffTrain()" on startTrain, then I will also have to send dineros and rep to getOffTrain if I wanna call printStats from there.
public class ACRE {
    
     /**
     * 
     * @param args not used.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dineros;
        int rep;
        char optionKey;
        dineros = 1500;
        rep = 100;
        optionKey = '0';
        ACRE game = new ACRE();
        game.startTrain(dineros, rep);
    }
     /**
     * Start of the game
     * 
     * @param dineros an integer number for the user's current money
     * @param rep an integer number for the user's current reputation
     * 
     */
    public void startTrain(int dineros, int rep) {
        printStats(dineros, rep);
        System.out.print("ur on a train. get off or nah etc etc");
        //show options here
    }
    /**
     * Print current money and reputation
     */
    public void printStats(int dineros, int rep) {
        System.out.print("Dinero: " + dineros + "D");
        System.out.print("  *   ");
        System.out.print("Reputación: " + rep + "\n");
    }
    
}

It seems a bit crazy to me that dineros and rep have to be jumping around and I'm sure there's a much better and more efficient way to do this (like if printStats got the variables directly from main) but I can't figure out how to.
Thanks

Welcome to the wonderful world of Object Oriented Programming.  Give it a try. You will like it.

Usually you'd put these variables as member variables into a class; that is one main idea of object oriented programming: keep the data with the functions (methods) that work with that data. You then initialize these variables in the constructor. All functions in the same class can access the variables (here your printStats, for example).
public class ACRE {
    private int dineros;
    private int rep;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ACRE game = new ACRE(1500, 100);
        game.startTrain();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new game
     * 
     * @param dineros an integer number for the user's starting money
     * @param rep an integer number for the user's starting reputation
     * 
     */
    public ACRE(int dineros, int rep) {
        // Use this.dineros and this.rep to make clear you're setting the object's variables.
        // You could also rename them to e.g., theDineros and then use just dineros = theDineros if you find that clearer.
        this.dineros = dineros;
        this.rep = rep;
    }

    public void startTrain() {
        printStats();
        System.out.print("ur on a train. get off or nah etc etc");
    }

    public void printStats() {
        System.out.print("Dinero: " + dineros + "D");
        System.out.print("  *   ");
        System.out.print("Reputación: " + rep + "\n");
    }
}

